# PHP Pear HTTP_Request force to use specified SSL version

Tags: php, ssl, pear, http-request

I use PHP Pear HTTP_Request class to do http(s) requests from my PHP application.
It is this library http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request/docs

I want to control what SSL version is used for https requests (SSLv3, tls1 etc).
Some part of my application uses curl and there is the option CURLOPT_SSLVERSION and it allows to do what i need.

I want to find the way to do same with the HTTP_Request library.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the solution.
So i had to modify the module Request.php from pear .
I replaced the line

```
$host = 'ssl://' . $host;
```

I added the new property where i can set a different ssl version. tls,sslv2,sslv3 instead of 'ssl://'

Answer (score 0):

The short answer (currently) is "No".

I searched the codebase for both http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request and http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2 - neither package supports specifying a CURLOPT_SSLVERSION at the moment - providing a patch for HTTP_Request2 would be the thing to do ;-)